# The destination and fate of Murderers

Tags: scripture, vedas, manu-smriti

I'd like to make clear the destination and fate of murders.

According to **Manusmriti 12.54-55**,

> Those who committed mortal sins (Mahapataka), having passed during large numbers of years through dreadful hells, obtain, after the expiration of (that term of punishment), the following births. The slayer of a Brahmana enters the womb of a dog, a pig, an ass, a camel, a cow, a goat, a sheep, a deer, a bird, a Candala, and a Pukkasa.

So, my question is this:

Will a killer of brahmana get a fate to be killed by the karmic reaction of his previous life, after long reincarnation from lower birth to the human body again?

If so, the murderer will suffer

1. Severe punishments in hell.
2. Will get lower birth and suffer birth and death many many times before getting the human body again and
3. Will be killed by his karmic reaction of murder in human life.

Committing sins are so foolish, isn't it? They will just cause many many suffering.

Comment: Dear Mr_Green, thank you for your correction of my writing. I hope everyone will not commit any violent acts by thinking, verbally and physically to our soul brothers and sisters in this world.